# Listing all users in user profile service using UserProfileManager and Linq

Tags: 2013, development, user-profile-service

I'm trying to return a list of all users in the user profile service using linq. Unfortunately I can't see a way to do this, and have become stumped at the following:

```
public List<SPUsersEntity> FetchItems(string siteName)
{
    try
    {
        PostEvent("Attempting to load users from: " + siteName, BaseExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Debug);

        using (var site = new SPSite(siteName))
        {
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                PostEvent("Successfully opened: " + web.Url, BaseExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Debug);

                var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                var userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

                //return (from UserProfile userProfile in userProfileManager
                //        select LoadItems(userProfile.AccountName.ToString, userProfile.DisplayName.ToString)).ToList();

                var userList = new List<SPUsersEntity>;

                return (from UserProfile user in userProfileManager
                        select LoadItems(user.Name.ToString(),
                                    user.LoginName.ToString())).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        PostEvent("Error fetching list of SharePoint Users", BaseExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Error, ex);

        throw;
    }
}
```

This is throwing an error because `UserProfileManager` isn't IQueryable. Is there another class or approach I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following class could be introduced for that purpose that implements [Enumerable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
class UserProfileTypedManager : UserProfileManager, IEnumerable<ProfileBase>
{
    public UserProfileTypedManager(SPServiceContext serviceContext) : base(serviceContext)
    {
    }

    public new IEnumerator<ProfileBase> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var e = base.GetEnumerator();
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return e.Current as ProfileBase;    
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return base.GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

Then you could apply LINQ Query Operations:

```
public static List<SPUsersEntity> FetchItems(SPSite site)
{
    var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    var userProfileManager = new UserProfileTypedManager(serviceContext);
    return (from UserProfile userProfile in userProfileManager select new SPUsersEntity() { LoginName = userProfile.DisplayName }).ToList();
}
```

**Usage**

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    var result = FetchItems(site);
    foreach (var userEntry in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(userEntry.LoginName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this process requires less time as compare to-
var srchResults = profileManager.GetEnumerator();
while (SrchResults.MoveNext()){//Code here}

Comment: What namespace I require for SPUsersEntity?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
var userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
foreach (UserProfile userProfile in userProfileManager)
{
    // ...
}
```

You will need elevated privileges to perform this operation